# Reactive or Computed for array

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

I wonder if I'm doing it correctly. Using Vue3 and Vuex4.

I got an array named `list` in my store, looking like this:

```
  const store = createStore({
    plugins: [createPersistedState()],
    state() {
      return {
        list: [{
            name:  makeid(7),
            id: makeid(5),
            group: {
                head: false,
                inGroup: 0,
                pos: 0.0
            }
        }]
}
```

To add/remove elements I use mutations with subsequently sorting the array.
In my componment I get the array like this:

`let list = reactive(store.getters.getList);`

Actions are called like:

```
store.dispatch('pushElement', el)
store.dispatch('removeElement', id)
```

The array updates as expected when using `reactive`. But I wonder if is preferred to use an `computed property` for the list instead of an reactive array? I already tried it with

```
list = computed () => {get()..., set()...}
```

But had problems removing an element from the array.

So, am I doing it right here?

EDIT:

As suggested I'm using a computed property now for the read-only aspect, like:

```
        let list = computed({
            get: () => {
                return store.getters.getList;
            }
        });
```

Comment: If I understood correctly the case, both are incorrect. Vuex state is supposed to be the single source of truth. `list` in the component needs to be read-only, i.e. a computed with no `set`.

Comment: @EstusFlask SO I have to put the maniulation completely into the store? But isn't that what I just did with the two `dispatch` for adding and removing the element?
Also `list` in the component is just set to a `getter`of the store.

Comment: *SO I have to put the maniulation completely into the store?* - yes, that's the goal of Vuex abstraction, otherwise you could just make `reactive` object available globally to all components and mutate it directly.  So yes, using a computed with no `set` is the way it can be seen in all Vuex examples.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks for the explanation. If you write an answer, I could accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to deal with this, was using a computed property without a setter at all. So the data manipulation is kept in the store:

```
        let list = computed({
            get: () => {
                return store.getters.getList;
            }
        });
```